# Boolean algebra: $(x+y)(x’+z)(y+z) = (x+y)(x’+z)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could someone explain to me how this simplification is derived?

$(x+y)(x’+z)(y+z) =  (x+y)(x’+z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}
(x + y)(x' + z)(y + z) & = (xz + x'y + yz)(y + z)\\
& = (xyz + xz + x'y + x'yz + yz + yz)\\
& = [xz(1 + y) + x'y(1 + z) + yz]\\
& = (xz + x'y + yz)\\
& = (x + y)(x' + z)\end{align}$

Comment: Perfect. I kept trying to avoid $1+A$, having forgotten that it was simply 1.